# ubuntu 14.04 no /etc/mysql folder after installing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install mysql and later phpmyadmin on a ubuntu 14.04 server after initial install.

So far I have configured Apache.

there is no mysql folder inside /etc/

I used the command 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server to install mysql

When I do this I have no prompt for a password and the mysql folder is still not created inside /etc/ but it says it installed anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: creating a webserver for local hostin

Comment: Okay! You are trying to install LAMP. Try to open mysql using `mysql -u USERNAME -p` in terminal. Can you access it?

Comment: I am creating a webserver for local testing and possibly hosting for future client sites.

I will be using mysql databases so I am trying to set this up on the server. 

but for some reason something seems to be wrong installing mysql

Comment: Also, first become a sudo user and then try to check if the folder exist!

Comment: what would the username and password be? It never asked me for these things when I installed it. 

I tryied root - root and get Can't connect to local MyySql server through socket '/var/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2)

Comment: Try using `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: Oh and maybe try to activate your MySQL using `sudo mysql_install_db`

Comment: mysql_secure_instalation
No command 'mysql_secure_instalation' found, did you mean:
 Command 'mysql_secure_installation' from package 'mysql-server-5.6' (universe)
 Command 'mysql_secure_installation' from package 'mariadb-server-5.5' (universe)
 Command 'mysql_secure_installation' from package 'percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5' (universe)
 Command 'mysql_secure_installation' from package 'mysql-server-5.5' (main)
mysql_secure_instalation: command not found

Comment: Oh wow.. didn't thought that would occur! Can you post result of `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and first do, `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge mysql-server`

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.

Comment: Did you try `sudo mysql_install_db` yet??

Comment: No sorry. Done that now. 

It seems to have installed

Comment: I guess now i need to start the service

Comment: Well, then I'd say you can mark my Answer as correct. I told you same thing in the answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd advice you to follow this link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Second, as mentioned in the link, sometimes (though in my case it took care of itself), you may need to activate MySQL installation using `sudo mysql_install_db`

Comment: In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: I still do not have a folder in /etc/ either /etc/mysql: No suck file or directory exists

Answer (score 0):

I found this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/392438/mysql-job-failed-to-start

After following the un-install commands and insatllign mysql-server I was prompted for the password.

Comment: Thays good. I guess you missed uninstall command. Even in future you can use `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge packagename` to completely remove certain package. But make sure you use this command only in emergency.